# Error:(34, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setup ViewPager(ViewPagerAndroid trying to implement material design tab

Tags: android, tabs, material-design

I am trying to implement the android material design tab. Below is part of my codes.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MainTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tab);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Here is the dependencies. I keep getting this error Error:(34, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setup ViewPager(ViewPager). I have tried various method where I google some say is to change AppCompatActivity  to activitybar etc. Tried all method it seems to be keep falling.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What could be wrong or should I tweak further to overcome this issue?

Below are the detail code.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new mapFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new mapFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new mapFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show full Stack trace

Comment: Error:(34, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setup ViewPager(ViewPager) where to get the stack trace?

Comment: Yes error log, but full not 1 line

Comment: Can you post code of this setupViewPager(viewPager);
` method ?

Comment: I have added ready to my codes.

Comment: I still don't see Stacktrace. The most important thing for debuging....

Comment: You mean the error log is it ?